# What is the best way to simulate split-brain?

Tags: failover, mysql-cluster

I have a Windows failover cluster and would like to test if it works in a split-brain scenario. The cluster consists of virtual machine in hyper-V. How would one go about doing this?

Comment: Block the members from contacting each other, perhaps using the firewall.

Comment: Hi and welcome to dba.se! Nothing about databases in the question, but you might want to look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_engineering). If you wish to return, please put something database related in your questions - you can always edit your own question!